# Rails 3 routes issue Routing Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

My **routes.rb**

```
resources :users do
    resources :requests , :only => [:new,:create,:destroy]
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :password
    attr_accessible :email, :firstname, :lastname, :state, :city, :password, :password_confirmation, :image
 # mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
 has_many :requests
```

**request.rb**

```
class Request < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :email, :status, :user_id
    belongs_to :user
end
```

After user login, from user.show page I'm passing a link

```
<li><span>  <%= link_to "Send Request" , new_user_request_path(@user)  %> </li>
```

My path is been displayed correct , but under request.new is not being displayed and I'm getting following error.

Routing Error

```
No route matches {:controller=>"users", :action=>"edit"}
```

I'm new to rails, can any one please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Please clean up your code examples, it's very hard to read.

Comment: I'm trying to clean up my code.I apologize for the inconvenience.

Comment: I'm trying to call action :new controller:request

Comment: If you indent your code by 4 spaces (or more) it will appear as a code snippet, which is easier to read.

Comment: Your error is referring to the `edit` action, which seems strange since you are calling the `new` action. Are you sure that is the correct error message?

Comment: Could you post your `Users` and `Requests` controllers? Perhaps it would be better if you put them in gist: gist.github.com

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are calling the `edit` action and not the `new` action. That would explain the error, since you need to pass a request to `edit_user_request_path` along with the user (since requests are nested resources), like this:

```
edit_user_request_path(@user, @request)
```

Please check your code again to see wherthe error is actually coming from.

Comment: I do not want edit_user_request, when click on the link it should take me to request/new.Currently when I click on send request link ,the url is http://localhost:3000/users/9/requests/new. And error shown on the page is Routing Error

No route matches {:controller=>"users", :action=>"edit"}
Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.

Comment: Then why is the error referring to the `edit` action? Something is missing from what you've written here.

Comment: In fact, it's also weird that it's referring to the `users` controller, since the request should be going to the `requests` controller. It looks like you have `edit_user_path` somewhere with no `@user` provided as an argument, which is totally different from what you're describing.

Comment: Not sure..I've been struggling on this for past 2 days.The request table consist of user_id,email,status where user_id is the foreign key.All I'm trying to achieve is an user can invite others through email.I'm trying to render new request form(_form)

Comment: You are right..I do have another link called my account  `<ul>
<li> <span id="welcome"> <%= link_to "Home" , @current_user %></span></li>
<li> <span id="welcome"> <%= link_to "My Account" ,  edit_user_path(@user) %></span></li>
    <li><span> <%= link_to "Send Request" , new_user_request_path(@user) %> </li>
  <li><span> <%= link_to "Sign out" ,signout_path ,:method => :delete %> </li>
   
    
     </ul>`

Comment: You're missing a closing `</span>` tag here: `<li><span> <%= link_to "Send Request" , new_user_request_path(@user) %> </li>`. That's probably screwing up the HTML so that you click on the edit link instead of the new request link.

Comment: How do I access requests/new ,hope my route.rb and new_user_request_path is correct and below is my rake routes output       [`user_requests POST   /users/:user_id/requests(.:format)     requests#create
new_user_request GET    /users/:user_id/requests/new(.:format) requests#new
    user_request DELETE /users/:user_id/requests/:id(.:format) requests#destroy
           users GET    /users(.:format)                       users#index
                 POST   /users(.:format)                       users#create`]

Comment: Did you try fixing the unclosed span tag? Start there.

Comment: yes..I did..      `<ul>
    <li> <span id="welcome"> <%= link_to "Home" , @current_user %></span></li>
    <li> <span id="welcome"> <%= link_to "My Account" ,  edit_user_path(@user) %></span></li>
    <li><span> <%= link_to "Send Request" , new_user_request_path(@user) %></span> </li>
  <li><span> <%= link_to "Sign out" ,signout_path ,:method => :delete %></span> </li>
   
    
     </ul>`

Comment: Sorry, I can't really help you any more than this.